# Biomedical consensus on human aging and lifespan

Tags: human-biology, medicine, senescence, health, healing

Medical technology is improving quickly. Unless there is a global disaster and human progress is set back significantly, e.g. by an asteroid or a global nuclear war, there will come a day when humans can live indefinitely. This does not mean infinitely- people will still die in vehicle accidents, get murdered, etc. Also, at least at first, access will be prohibitive due to costs and possibly outright selection/rejection of patients.

Based on trends in the progress of biomedical research, what is the consensus in the biomedical research community for approximately what year will the average person vs. a very elite person be able to get treatment to live indefinitely?

Comment: This question is being voted to be closed as "primarily opinion based" because 1. your premise "...there will come a day when humans can live indefinitely" is strictly opinion and not currently substantiated by any major research that I know about, and 2. your question about the consensus of the biomedical community (which there likely isn't one due to there being no way for us to know) will likely only lead to answers "almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise".